# Cantor set (definition) in general

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, cantor-set

The question is if in the Cantor sets general is needed that its measuare is 0 or not.

And in what book or books is there that definiton?

Comment: The "middle thirds" Cantor set has measure zero, but with a simple modification, one can obtain a set with positive measure: a so-called "fat Cantor set". See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set

Comment: A followup to Bungo's comment: the middle thirds Cantor set is frequently referred to as *the* Cantor set. The others are just "Cantor sets".

Comment: If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

When people talk about *the* Cantor set, they very often have in mind the [middle-thirds Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), which does have Lebesgue measure $0$. This measure property is not part of the definition, however. Topologically, any non-empty compact, zero-dimensional metric space is a Cantor set, and given any non-negative real number $r$ there is a Cantor subset of the line of Lebesgue measure $r$. The [Smith-Volterra Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) is an example of one with positive Lebesgue measure.